# How to get rid of blue outer border when clicking on a form input field?

Tags: html, forms, textfield

Hi I want to get rid of the blue "shine" that appears when you click on a text field and begin to input data. How is this done?

I am a beginner so I am not that experienced.
My code is:

```
<input type="text" name="search" size="40" value="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager"  
style="background-color:white; border: 
solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 31px; font-size:16px; 
vertical-align:0px;color:#bbb" 
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager'){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#000'}" />
```

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This **CSS** snippet should work in all major browsers:

```css
    input:focus {
        outline:none;
    }
```

If it doesn't, try adding the `!important` directive:

```css
    input:focus {
        outline:none !important;
    }
```

Comment: If some div is clickable, this works too `div:focus { outline: none; }` to get rid of the blue outline.

Answer (score 5):

You simply add:

```
<style type="text/css">
#hello:focus
{
  outline:none;
}    
</style>



<input type="text" id="hello"></input>
```

cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can use below style property on element to avoid blue border.

```html
style="box-shadow: none;"
```

For example:
Here, I've used in my button

```html
<button type="button" style="box-shadow: none;">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not directly related, I leave a note here since this SO page is what came up in my search. The answers listed here also work for html5 videos. In my case, there was a blue border showing underneath the video in Chrome.

For completeness sake:

```
video 
{
  outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want easy solution and want to remove blue border from complete html, use

```
*:focus {outline:none !important}
```