# How do I remove the blue border that appears when clicking on a uib-accordion-heading?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've tried the solutions presented in the following questions to no avail:

[Remove blue border from css custom-styled button in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)

[How to remove the blue box shadow border in button if clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222798/how-to-remove-the-blue-box-shadow-border-in-button-if-clicked)

[How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

[How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

[Remove blue "selected" outline on buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593224/remove-blue-selected-outline-on-buttons)

[Anyway to prevent the Blue highlighting of elements in Chrome when clicking quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003535/anyway-to-prevent-the-blue-highlighting-of-elements-in-chrome-when-clicking-quic)

[bootstrap button shows blue outline when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333231/bootstrap-button-shows-blue-outline-when-clicked)

[How to get rid of blue outer border when clicking on a form input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648898/how-to-get-rid-of-blue-outer-border-when-clicking-on-a-form-input-field)

In HTML I have the following:

```
<uib-accordion-heading>
    <div id="fart1" ng-if="!contactsAccordionIsOpen" class="noSelect" style="outline: none;">Contacts<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span></div>
    <div id="fart2" ng-if="contactsAccordionIsOpen" class="noSelect" style="outline: none;">Contacts<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign pull-right"></span></div>
</uib-accordion-heading>
```

The blue outline doesn't appear around the entire accordion header, but form fits around the text. I've tried inline styling, selection by ID and class, but even with `!important` it doesn't change.

In CSS I have:

```
#fart1:focus {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#fart2:focus {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.noSelect {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -khtml-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
}
```

I've also tried swapping `outline: none` for `outline: 0` but it didn't change anything.

Link to my CSS file: https://jsfiddle.net/8wnd2nz5/

EDIT -- Attached an image to illustrate what I'm referring to.

[image: Blue Outline]

Comment: I think we need a live example here, since you insist nothing is working.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what kind of border you're describing. Could you provide an image? Taking a guess based on your mention of the effect from individual characters of text, perhaps this is caused by a `text-shadow` or `box-shadow`.

Comment: just `:focus {outline: 0;}` try this.

Comment: @Gwellin Added an image.

Comment: @Legion share code snippet

Comment: @cnsvnc That's all the relevant code. If I included all non-relevant code that would be over a hundred files and thousands of lines.

Comment: @Legion i think other css files include , and block this css ?

Comment: @cnsvnc The only css files I didn't make are `bootstrap.min.css` and `font-awesome.min.css`. I've updated the question with a link to a jsfiddle containing my css file.

Comment: @Legion i saw this code and run your html but i cant see focus border. :/

Comment: @cnsvnc In Chrome it's a blue border like in the image. In Internet Explorer 8 it's an underline beneath the text.

Comment: @Legion try like this `:focus {outline:0 !important;}`

Comment: Doesn't appear here when running via jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/8wnd2nz5/1/

Comment: @cnsvnc `:focus {outline:0 !important;}` worked! Make it an answer and I'll accept it. It's weird that placing `outline: 0 !important;` in my `noSelect` class doesn't work.

Comment: @Legion finally! everything is okay?

Comment: @cnsvnc yes, all good now

Comment: @Legion the border is a critical accessibility feature (very important for keyboard navigation). If you remove it you must replace it with another visual cue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Solution**

```
:focus {outline:0 !important;}
```

This code all focus border remove.

Answer (score 34):

Everyone who has a problem with `not working outline: 0/none` - try to set:

```
:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Comment: This should be top answer. Thanks. This issue was massively triggering my OCD.

Comment: This should be the top answer.  The top answer didn't resolve issue, but this one did.

Comment: Best possible answer.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome is adding the blue line for accessability reason. You can remove it by adding this to your CSS. But note that this is kind of "brute force" to hide all focus outlines that may help users to find the focused element.

```
*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this setting the outline of the element to none.

```
.element {
  outline: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    .ui-accordion {
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       /*Removes all outlines*/
       :focus {
         outline: 0 !important;
         box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The blue line came on the bottom of my word document when I  took too long to close it.

I got rid of that line when I clicked, in the upper right hand corner, the box to make the screen larger.

Comment: Hello Paula, thanks for your answer. You should read the question though. Your answer is missing the point.